# clear GVnix datatables filter

Tags: spring-mvc, datatables, spring-roo, gvnix, gvnix-es

whit gvnix-2.0.0.M1

the filter (automatic input generated) for search in table persist value after submit or close or reload page

I need clear this

[image: example for filter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatables componentes stores that values using the `localStorage` feature provided your browser.

Use the `localStorage.clear()` javascript function to clear the values of your component.

Read more about the `localStorage` here:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

If you need DT, I recommend you the latest release of Spring Roo, the version RC1.

http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/

Hope it helps.